Custom Spring WebFlux HandlerMethodArgumentResolver is NOT executed
I want to convert a sort query parameter like sort=id,-created_at to a Map<String, Boolean> like the following, then pass it to the further query service to handle the query.
mapOf(
  "id" to true, // asc order in the further query
  "created_at" to false // desc order in the further query
)

I tried to write a custom HandlerMethodArgumentResolver to resolve the query params and convert the value to a Map.
class SimpleSortMapHandlerMethodArgumentResolver : SyncHandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    override fun supportsParameter(parameter: MethodParameter): Boolean {
        log.debug("method param: {}", parameter)
        return Map::class.java.isAssignableFrom(parameter.parameterType)
    }

    override fun resolveArgumentValue(
        parameter: MethodParameter,
        bindingContext: BindingContext,
        exchange: ServerWebExchange
    ): Any {
        val params = exchange.request.queryParams[parameter.parameterName]
        log.debug("resolved args: $params")
        if (params.isNullOrEmpty()) return emptyMap<String, Boolean>()

        val paramValues = params[0].split(",").map { it.trim() }
            .groupBy({ it -> if (it.startsWith("-")) it.substring(1) else it }, { it -> !it.startsWith("-") })
            .mapValues { it.value.first() }
        log.debug("converted sort result: $paramValues")
        return paramValues
    }

    companion object {
        private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleSortMapHandlerMethodArgumentResolver::class.java)
    }
}

And I tried to register it via WebFluxConfigurer or declare it as a @Bean.
@Configuration
class WebConfig : WebFluxConfigurer {

    override fun configureArgumentResolvers(configurer: ArgumentResolverConfigurer) {
        configurer.addCustomResolver(SimpleSortMapHandlerMethodArgumentResolver())
    }

//    @Bean
//    @Order(0)
//    fun simpleSortMapHandlerMethodArgumentResolver() = SimpleSortMapHandlerMethodArgumentResolver()
}

But neither is working.
The the Map in the controller is always empty.
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/messages")
class MessageController(private val messages: MessageRepository) {


    @GetMapping("")
    fun getAll(sort: Map<String, Boolean>): List<Message> {
        log.debug("sort by: $sort")
        return messages.getAll(sort)
    }

    companion object{
        private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageController::class.java)
    }
}

The complete project codes are shared on Github, check here, https://github.com/hantsy/spring-puzzles/tree/master/webflux-method-arg-resolver
When running the application, and accessing the endpoint http://localhost:8080/messsages?sort=id or  http://localhost:8080/messsages?sort=-id, the sort value in the controller method is always empty.
